# Android default constructor in Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, constructor

Based on the following statement from the official documentation [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html);

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument
>   constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class
>   when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able
>   to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the no-argument
>   constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some
>   cases during state restore.

It seems that we have to create a public no-argument constructor for any Fragment or Dialog as framework would **often re-instantiate** when needed. Well, the word "re-instantiate" looks very dangerous to me. Now here is my question. I have a Dialog with default constructor as `Dialog(Context)`. It is all nice and working. In the APK release, I am getting this error

> Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public
>   constructor with no arguments)

Now, I have some final variables in this Dialog which I initialize on the default constructor call `Dialog(Context)`. But now I am required to create an empty constructor for the framework. At this point, I am failing to initialize my final variables.

Well, I can sacrifice the final keyword for my variables. But one point makes me worried. If the framework re-instantiate my dialog, that means I am getting a new instance. And what happens to my old instance? Are my old variables re-created or simply swapped with the new instance?

Comment: Just initialize your final variables in the no-argument constructor and call that -- or better yet, do it on declaration, if possible. If you need to maintain state, use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: @323go Yes but what happens to my previous final variables then?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static YourDialogFragment newInstance(SearchInfo searchInfo) {
      YourDialogFragment fragment = new YourDialogFragment();
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putParcelable("key", yourdata);
      fragment.setArguments(bundle);
      return fragment;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Bundle bundle = getArguments();
      if (bundle != null) {
         searchInfo = bundle.getParcelable(key);
      }
   }
```

And you can call your dialog fragment

```
    YourDialogFragmentsearchDialogFragment=YourDialogFragment.newInstance(searchInfo);
searchDialogFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager, "your tag");
```

Comment: But not all my final variables are parcelable. This won't solve it.  :(

Comment: @OmerHalit please can you add arguments or class?